# I thought about it "whole the day" or "all the day"?

Tags: word-choice

If I want to say that I thought about something in the entire day (one day 12 hours) then how should I say

> "I thought about it **all** the day"

or

> "I thought about it **whole** the day"?

Comment: I  thought about it ***all day or the whole day***.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thinking about something for a prolonged period of time such as the entire day implies that you are in the process of thinking that's continual. This suggests that the past continuous tense might possibly be a better choice of words to use in this situation. In fact, any continuous tense form with reference to the past will work here:

> I **was thinking** about it **all day**.
>
> I'**ve been thinking** about it **all day**.

However, note that the simple past is also fine:

> I **thought** about it **all day**.

The expression *all the day* is not going to be very idiomatic in this particular case. *all day* is the idiomatic one (and by that I mean that's what's actually going to be used in this situation). *whole the day* is grammatically downright wrong. Articles in English always come before the nouns or noun phrases that they modify. Hence, it should be *the whole day*. But you can use it too:

> I was thinking about it **the whole day**.
>
> I've spent **the whole day** thinking about it.
>
> I **thought** about it **the whole day**.

Comment: better, I've (had)been thinking about it all day

Comment: @user159691 Yep, that works too. But we'll leave it to the OP's discretion to choose which one of the possible contentious tenses he or she wants to use.

Comment: You raise an interesting point here, but I still think the simple past works just fine. There's nothing wrong with: _"I thought about it all day."_

Comment: @J.R. Thank you for your comment. I didn't explicitly say that it was wrong. I just didn't include it in my answer. I thought that past continuous tenses are more commonly used for this type of situation.